# Multiple inputs to switches in MATLAB Simulink Stateflow

Tags: matlab, model, switch-statement, simulink, stateflow

I want to model a turning light from a car. To this end, I need to specify the user input for the trigger. So far I have used two binary switches - one for the turning light right and one for the turning light left. But this does not satisfy my needs, because e.g. both can be on at the same time. What I need is , in my opinion, a way to either a) have a switch with three inputs which resembles exactly what I need or b) make switch A go into off-mode once I turn switch B on.

What would be the easiest way to achieve this? I am new to this and didnt even really know how to search for an answer...

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Have you seen the [Multiport Switch](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/multiportswitch.html) block?

Answer (score 0):

This would be easy to represent with [state machines](http://www.mathworks.com/products/stateflow). Represent the 3 modes of operation of the system as states:
 - OFF 
 - LightA_on
 - LightB_on

Represent the 2 switches as input values. Transition between the states based on the input values.